# communication between polipo and tor kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, tor, polipo

Where can I add `socksParentProxy` in Kubernetes deployment file to communicate polipo with tor. I already created tor service `tor:9150` and tor deployment. Here is a my YAML file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: polipo-deployment
    labels: 
        app: myauto
spec:
    selector:
        matchLabels:
          name: polipo-pod
          app: myauto
    template:
        metadata:
            name: polipo-deployment
            labels:
                name: polipo-pod
                app: myauto
        spec:
           containers:
              - env:
                    - name: socksParentProxy
                      value: tor:9150
                name: polipo
                image: 'clue/polipo'
                ports: 
                  - containerPort: 8123  
    replicas: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/), you should use `args`:

```
containers:
    name: polipo
    image: 'clue/polipo'
    args: ["socksParentProxy=tor:9150"]
    ports: 
        - containerPort: 8123
```